# Remove elements in an array containing a certain word/string in a single line of statement

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an array:

```
 List<String> TagArray = new List<string>(TagString.Split(','));
```

I want to remove certain elements, in the array; say - if the values contain the letter 'AAA'.

Is there a single line of statement in C# by which we can achieve the desired result?

Comment: Have you _ever_ try to use `Where()`?

Comment: No i haven't used it.

Comment: @Venkat  see my answer, i believe thats what you're looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
TagArray.RemoveAll(item => item.Contains("AAA"));
```

RemoveAll will remove all the items that would return true from the predicate you define. You can do this multiple time or you can || a bunch of contains together within one RemoveAll.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ here. For example

```
List<String> TagArray = TagString.Split(',')
    .Where(tag => tab.IndexOf("AAA") < 0)
    .ToList();
```

Remember to add `System.Linq` namespace.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string TagString = "WAAAA,APPLE";

        List<String> TagArray = new List<string>(TagString.ToUpper().Split(',')).Where(x => !x.Contains("AAA")).ToList();

    }
```

1 line and it works

```
 List<String> TagArray = new List<string>(TagString.ToUpper().Split(',')).Where(x => !x.Contains("AAA")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method available in List<T> : [RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var list = new List<string> {"AAABBBCCC", "AABBCC", "ABC", "CCAAACC"};
list.RemoveAll(s => s.Contains("AAA")); // Removes the first and the last element
```

`RemoveAll()` "iterates" over the list and provides you each element. The `s` represents an element from the list and the code after `=>` is a condition. When the condition is `true`, the element is removed. The condition doesn't have to use the `s` variable, it can be arbitrary block that returns `bool` value.

So you can also write this:

```
list.RemoveAll(s =>
{
    return a == 5;
});
```